# Blackberry RepeatRule

Tags: events, blackberry, repeat

I am very new to Blackberry development.

I am trying to access the Blackberry Events (Calender) list.

Currently, I am able to read the basic information from the event list.

I am stuck in getting the info regarding the RepeatRule.

My code is as below:

```
EventList eventList = (EventList)PIM.getInstance().openPIMList(PIM.EVENT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY);  
Enumeration e = eventList.items();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {  
    Event event = (Event)e.nextElement();
    RepeatRule rRule = event.getRepeat() ;
    if (rRule != null) {
        fieldIds = rRule.getFields() ;
        // Here I get the values as { 0,128,64,2}. How do I decode this information?

    }
}
```

Can any one help in decoding this information. Any kind of links, examples or pointers would be of great help.

Thanks and regards,
Vinay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the [documentation from the API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/pim/RepeatRule.html), and the documents it refers to? It seems quite extensive. The getFields method "returns a list of fields that currently have values assigned". So presumably what ever fields correspond to the constants 0, 128, 64 and 2 have values assigned, which you would get by calling getInt(0), getInt(128)...

Comment: Thanks Richard. But still I have some confusion. Could you please clarify me. When I refer to const 0 it is Frequency, but the next 128 has 2 different names INTERVAL and THIRDLAST. Similarly, for 64 I see, SECONDLAST and END. Same is the case for 2 DAY_IN_WEEK and SECOND.   Is there any other rule which needs to be referred for me to decode.  Kindly, enlighten me on this.

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation? INTERVAL is a field constant, THIRDLAST is a valid value for the field WEEK_IN_MONTH. Similarly END is a field constant, SECONDLAST is a value for WEEK_IN_MONTH. DAY_IN_WEEK is a field, etc. Since the values you gave came from getFields() they are to be interpreted as field constants, not values.